# How to send stream trough socket when using select()?

Tags: python, python-2.7, sockets, polling

After long hours of research and testing I finally ask here.

My script has to handle multiple client connections and in the same time has to get and send a stream from another socket.

Finally I've been able to make it work but only for one user. That user connects to the socket, the script connects to the other socket, then return the stream to the client.
The script works pretty well but has a some hard limitations :
- it send the stream to the client but,
- even if the socket is in non-blocking mode I think that calling a socket inside another one is the main reason why it reacts like it was in blocking mode (because one ot these is continuously sending datas ?)

By the way I think that the select() method could allow me to do what I want, but I don't clearly understand how.

Here is the server code taht works for one client, but is blocking

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding: utf-8 

from __future__ import print_function

import sys, time, base64, socket

server_ip = 'XX.XX.XX.XX'

def caster_connect(connected_client, address):
    username = 'XXXXXXX'
    password = 'XXXXXXXXX'
    host = 'XX.XX.XX.XX'
    port = 2102
    pwd = base64.b64encode("{}:{}".format(username, password).encode('ascii'))
    pwd = pwd.decode('ascii')
    u_message = ''
    stream_type = 'CMRp'

    header = \
    "GET /" + str(stream_type) + " HTTP/1.1\r\n" +\
    "Host " + str(host) + "\r\n" +\
    "Ntrip-Version: Ntrip/1.0\r\n" +\
    "User-Agent: my_script.py/0.1\r\n" +\
    "Accept: */*\r\n" +\
    "Authorization: Basic {}\r\n\r\n".format(pwd) +\
    "Connection: close\r\n"

    print("Connecting to caster...\n")

    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.connect((host,int(port)))
    s.send(header.encode('ascii'))
    print("Waiting answer from caster...\n")

    while True:
        try:
            data = s.recv(2048)

            connected_client.send(data)
            print("Sending data from caster at %s" % time.time())
            sys.stdout.flush()
        # On any error, close sockets
        except socket.error, e:
            print("No data received from caster : %s" % e)
            print("Close client connection at %s" % format(address))
            s.close()
            break

    return

#----------------

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
sock.bind((server_ip, 5680))
sock.settimeout(3)

try:
    while True:
        try:
            sock.listen(5)
            client, address = sock.accept()
            print ("%s connected" % format(address) )

            msg = client.recv(4096)
        except socket.timeout, e:
            err = e.args[0]
            if err == 'timed out':
                print("Timed out, retry later")
                continue
            else:
                print(socket.error)
                sock.close()
        except socket.error:
            print(socket.error)
            sock.close()
        else:
            if len(msg) == 0:
                print("Shutdown on client end")
                sock.close()
            else:
                print(msg)
                caster_response = caster_connect(client, address)
        sys.stdout.flush()

    print("Close")
    client.close()
    sock.close()`enter code here`
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("W: Keyboard interrupt, closing socket")
finally:
    sock.close()
```

And this is the code I found to handle select()

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding: utf-8 

import select, socket, sys, Queue

server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.setblocking(0)
server.bind(('XX.XX.XX.XX', 64000))
server.listen(5)
inputs = [server]
outputs = []
message_queues = {}

while inputs:
    readable, writable, exceptional = select.select(
        inputs, outputs, inputs)

    for s in readable:
        if s is server:
            connection, client_address = s.accept()
            print("New connection from %s" % client_address)
            connection.setblocking(0)
            inputs.append(connection)
            message_queues[connection] = Queue.Queue()
        else:
            data = s.recv(1024)
            print("Data received : %s" % data)
            if data:
                message_queues[s].put(data)
                if s not in outputs:
                    outputs.append(s)
            else:
                if s in outputs:
                    outputs.remove(s)
                inputs.remove(s)
                s.close()
                del message_queues[s]

    for s in writable:
        try:
            next_msg = message_queues[s].get_nowait()
            print("Next msg : %s" % next_msg)
        except Queue.Empty:
            outputs.remove(s)
        else:
            s.send(next_msg)

    for s in exceptional:
        inputs.remove(s)
        if s in outputs:
            outputs.remove(s)
        s.close()
        del message_queues[s]
```

In this code (found at [this page](https://pymotw.com/2/select/)) I didn't make changes as I don't know how to handle this.

Maybe by creating another server script that would only handle the stream part, so the main script would act as a server for clients, but as client for the stream part ?

Comment: A [mcve] will be more comprehensible than the _description_ of what your code does or is supposed to do.

Comment: Consider using a networking framework like [Twisted](https://twistedmatrix.com/),

Comment: @ForceBru : As suggested I added the code example.

Comment: @Robᵩ : I've tryied ZMQ but, don't know why because with another client it was working, with the client of my customer it didn't work at all and I was forced to use raw sockets. So I fear Twisted will end with the same result.